# Adding variable automatically when checkbox is checked Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

Is it possible to make arithmetic calculation automatically when checkbox is pressed? I want to add the total harga (total price) change based the choice of checkbox topping prices and add them with the basic prices (product price).

ex:
checked CB Extra Ayam and CB Kepala will add 3000 + 4000
then add it with basic product price 10000
so the total price would be 17000
and the total price will back to 10000 when im unchecked CB Extra Ayam and CB Kepala and so on

[image: screenshoot]

Here is my code

```
if (Code.toUpperCase().matches((inMieAyam.toUpperCase()))){
            
    //set text topping
    CBTopping1.setText("Extra Ayam");
    CBTopping2.setText("Extra Tetelan Sapi");
    CBTopping3.setText("Cakar (2 pcs)");
    CBTopping4.setText("Kepala");
    CBTopping5.setText("Bakso Sapi");
    CBTopping6.setText("Telur Mata Sapi");
    CBTopping7.setText("Balungan Rica Ayam");
    CBTopping8.setText("Extra Sawi");
    CBTopping9.setText("Extra Acar");

    //hide remaining topping CB
    CBTopping10.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //set price to variable
    Price1 = 3000;
    Price2 = 7000;
    Price3 = 4000;
    Price4 = 4000;
    Price5 = 3000;
    Price6 = 4000;
    Price7 = 4000;
    Price8 = 1000;
    Price9 = 1000;
    Price10 = 0;

    //set price topping
    TxtvToppingPrice1.setText("Rp."+Price1);
    TxtvToppingPrice2.setText("Rp."+Price2);
    TxtvToppingPrice3.setText("Rp."+Price3);
    TxtvToppingPrice4.setText("Rp."+Price4);
    TxtvToppingPrice5.setText("Rp."+Price5);
    TxtvToppingPrice6.setText("Rp."+Price6);
    TxtvToppingPrice7.setText("Rp."+Price7);
    TxtvToppingPrice8.setText("Rp."+Price8);
    TxtvToppingPrice9.setText("Rp."+Price9);


    //hide remaining topping price Txtv
    TxtvToppingPrice10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    

    FinalPrice1 = 0;
    FinalPrice2 = 0;
    FinalPrice3 = 0;
    FinalPrice4 = 0;
    FinalPrice5 = 0;
    FinalPrice6 = 0;
    FinalPrice7 = 0;
    FinalPrice8 = 0;
    FinalPrice9 = 0;
    FinalPrice10 = 0;

    CBTopping1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice1 = Price1;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice1 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice2 = Price2;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice2 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice3 = Price3;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice3 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice4 = Price4;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice4 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice5 = Price5;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice5 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice6 = Price6;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice6 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice7 = Price7;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice7 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice8 = Price8;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice8 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    CBTopping9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                FinalPrice9 = Price9;
            }
            else {
                FinalPrice9 = 0;
            }
        }
    });


    FoodPrice1 = Integer.parseInt(Price);
    TotalFinalPrice = FoodPrice1 + FinalPrice1 + FinalPrice2 + FinalPrice3 +
            FinalPrice4 + FinalPrice5 + FinalPrice6 +
            FinalPrice7 + FinalPrice8 + FinalPrice9 ;

    TxtvTotalHarga.setText(Integer.toString(TotalFinalPrice));

}
```

edit :
turn out the variables is not changed in the checkbox listener

default `FinalPrice1` is 0 when im changed it from checkbox listener it would not change to `Price1` values, it still 0. I tried to change it directly by writing value to it `FinalPrice1 = 10000` also no luck it just say 0.

if I remove the

```
            FinalPrice1 = 0;
            FinalPrice2 = 0;
            FinalPrice3 = 0;
            FinalPrice4 = 0;
            FinalPrice5 = 0;
            FinalPrice6 = 0;
            FinalPrice7 = 0;
            FinalPrice8 = 0;
            FinalPrice9 = 0;
            FinalPrice10 = 0;
```

it would be `nullpointer` error
i dont know whats wrong

i cant paste the whole code because the post didn't allow it, its too long lmao

the variable of the `TotalFinalPrice` just not changed or maybe not calculated

Answer (score 1):

When your TextView have to be updated, use `invalidate()` method.
This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

For your case use `TxtvTotalHarga.invalidate();`.

Comment: where should I use it ? after ```TxtvTotalHarga.setText(Integer.toString(TotalFinalPrice));``` ?

Comment: In your listeners.
Example:
`if (isChecked){ FinalPrice1 = Price1; //invalidate } else { FinalPrice1 = 0;
//invalidate}`

Comment: hmmm no luck same as before

Comment: turn out the variable wont change inside of checkbox listener , it stays 0 as default I declare i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first handle your objects into arrays, using tag value to save initial prices, create one event listener ( handle using object'd getTag() or array index....

And important: move the setOn..... out of the if. These call should be done onStart, before you trigger this event.

And can yoi also give more code on the context that this big if is calling?

Did you debug with AS to see these events triggered?

Comment: hmmmm it good idea but i dont really sure how to do it, 

i think i cant do that because this big if else used to other menu as well 

i'll give the full code 

yes i debug it with android studio ...

Comment: turn out i cant paste the whole code in the post because it surpases the limit character of the post

Comment: Can you just try to change one Price1 OnCheckListener to onClickListener and check if it can fix thre value update?

Comment: Also, add a breakpoint when debug to see if any other reason caused it rechecked, so toggled the value.

Comment: im trying change FinalPrice1 to Price1 value then display it on test textview , when im check the checkbox its still not change the value of the text

Comment: I setText the textview test at outside of listener